# Remove bash autload in terminal

Tags: bash

My terminal tries to start cgminer when it's opened, but cgminer is not installed. How do I remove cgminer from the autoload? It's not in the bash profile file.

Error: -bash: cgminer: command not found

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. GoodLuck

Answer (score 0):

The `bash` program will execute a few profiles. You can check which ones to start with by issuing the command:

```
man bash
```

Skip to the end, and you will find the ones used on your particular operating system. On one of my computers, the list looks like:

- /etc/profile
- ~/.bash_profile
- ~/.bashrc
- ~/.inputc

Different versions and different operating systems may have others.

Comment: Each of those files could source an arbitrary set of files itself (for instance, if both `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` are source, it's probably because `.bash_profile` sources `.bashrc` explicitly). Run `bash -lx` to start a login shell that logs every command executed during startup; you should be able to dig through that for `cgminer` and determine which file contains the offending command.